# (Unity Help) How can I get my bullet object to automatically move in a direction after a button input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

(Unity Help) How can I get my bullet object to automatically move in a direction after a button input?

I have some c# code already set up, it just won't move by itself. (Excuse my messy code)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine:

public class script : MonoBehaviour { 
public SpriteRenderer ellie; 
public GameObject ellie_sprite; 
public Rigidbody2D ellie_rb; 
public float jumpStrength; 
public float speed; public 
float direction = 0f;

public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public LayerMask Floor;
public bool isGround;

public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform bulletPrefab_tr;
public Rigidbody2D bullet_rb;
public float bullet_speed;
public float directionFacing;

//Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ellie_rb.freezeRotation = true;
}

//Update is called once every frame
void Update()
{
    
    //Ground Check Variable

    isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius * 2, Floor);

    //Movement Variables

    direction = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    ellie_rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, ellie_rb.velocity.y);

    //Direction check and flip sprite code

    if(direction > 0f)
    {
        ellie_rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, ellie_rb.velocity.y);
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(0.25f,0.25f);
        firePoint.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f,0,0);
        directionFacing = 1;
    }
    else if(direction < 0f)
    {
        ellie_rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, ellie_rb.velocity.y);
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(-0.25f,0.25f);
        firePoint.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.5f,0,0);
        directionFacing = -1;
    }

    //Jumping and Ground Check
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true && isGround == true)
    {
        ellie_rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpStrength;
    }

    //Check for Shoot Key Press and input direction
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Shoot(directionFacing);
    }
}

    void Shoot(float directionFacing)
    {
    //Shooting Logic
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    bullet_rb.velocity = Vector3.right * directionFacing * bullet_speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

The bullet to move across the x axis (right or left) with an adjustable variable for speed.

I can spawn the bullet prefab but it won't move unless pushed by another game object.

How do I fix this as I think this theoretically think that this should work... it doesn't.

Comment: Instantiate returns the created game object - I'm guessing you want to set velocity on that rather than your "bullet_rb" field. Something like Instantiate(...).GetComponent<RidgidBody>.velocity = x

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not using [Object.Instantiate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) correctly in your code - if you glance at the documentation, you'll find this line summarizing what it does:

> Clones the object original and **returns the clone**.

Now, let's look at the pertinent part of your code:

```cs
Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
bullet_rb.velocity = Vector3.right * directionFacing * bullet_speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

There are three issues here:

1. You aren't using the return value of `Object.Instantiate()` in any way.
2. As a result, you're manipulating the velocity of a rigidbody that is not related at all to the bullet you just instantiated.
3. You shouldn't multiply velocity by `Time.deltaTime`, because the physics system will already be moving the object according to game time. As per the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html), the velocity is in "units per second", so you should set it independently of the last frame time.

So to correct these issues, you might rewrite your code as:

```cs
// Store the returned clone
GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
// Get the rigidbody associated with the clone
Rigidbody2D newBulletRb = newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
// Set the velocity on the correct rigidbody
newBulletRb.velocity = Vector3.right * directionFacing * bullet_speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a bullet object move in a specific direction in Unity, you can add a Rigidbody component to the bullet and then use the AddForce() function to apply a force to the bullet in the desired direction. Here's an example code snippet:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f; // Speed of the bullet
    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward; // Direction the bullet should move in

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddForce(direction * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

In this code, the speed and direction of the bullet are set as public variables that can be adjusted in the inspector. The direction is set to Vector3.forward by default, which is the positive z-axis in Unity's world space.

In the Start() method, we get a reference to the Rigidbody component on the bullet and then use AddForce() to apply a force in the direction specified by the direction vector, with a magnitude determined by the speed variable. We use the ForceMode.Impulse parameter to make the bullet move instantly rather than accelerating gradually.

With this code, the bullet object will move in the specified direction as soon as it is instantiated in the scene.